# sparql wikidata question : how to get several labels?

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I want to get the xLabel and the nodeLabel at the same time...

```
SELECT ?x ?xLabel ?dn ?dd ?de ?df ?nodetext
WHERE {
?x p:P39 ?node.
?node ps:P39 wd:Q70495953.    #on sélectionne les éléments qui sont membres Academie francaise
OPTIONAL {?node pq:P580 ?de.}
OPTIONAL {?node pq:P582 ?df.}
OPTIONAL {?x wdt:P569 ?dn.}
OPTIONAL {?x wdt:P570 ?dd.}
SERVICE wikibase:label { 
 bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". 
 wd:Q70495953 rdfs:label ?nodetext .}
}
```

but with this query, I can get the node Label but not the item Label (the name of the Seat holder)...

https://w.wiki/7Kvn

Comment: once you manually assign labels to variables in the label `SERVICE` you have to do it for all others as well because this overrides the default style: `SERVICE wikibase:label { 
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". 
     wd:Q70495953 rdfs:label ?nodetext .
     ?x rdfs:label ?xLabel .
   }`

Comment: the other option is to don't hard code the label retrieval and simply make it flexible: `SELECT ?x ?xLabel ?dn ?dd ?de ?df ?nodeLabel
WHERE {
   BIND(wd:Q70495953 AS ?node)
   ?x p:P39 ?stmt.
   ?stmt ps:P39 ?node .
   OPTIONAL {?stmt pq:P580 ?de.}
   OPTIONAL {?stmt pq:P582 ?df.}
   OPTIONAL {?x wdt:P569 ?dn.}
   OPTIONAL {?x wdt:P570 ?dd.}
   SERVICE wikibase:label { 
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". 
   }
}`